# How to put int arrays into int 2d matrix in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, memory, integer

I wrote this(memory error) when I try to put int arrays into int matrix:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout; using std::endl;

int* intToIntArray(int input, int length) {
    int output[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        output[i] = input % 10;
        input /= 10;
        cout << output[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "=====" << endl;
    return output;
}

int main() {
    const int arraySize = 5;
    int a[arraySize] = { 111110, 1111000, 11100000, 110000000, 1000000000 };
    int NumSize[arraySize] = { 6,7,8,9,10 };
    int* arr1D;
    int** arr2D = new int*;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < arraySize; counter++) {
        cout << a[counter] << endl;
        arr1D = intToIntArray(a[counter], NumSize[counter]);
        arr2D[counter] = arr1D;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NumSize[i]; j++) {
            cout << arr2D[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I know how to put the data from int arrays to a int matrix, but very very inefficient:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout; using std::endl;

int* intToIntArray(int input, int length) {
    int output[20];
    for (int i = length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        output[i] = input % 10;
        input /= 10;
        cout << output[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "=====" << endl;
    return output;
}

int main() {
    const int arraySize = 5;
    int a[arraySize] = { 111110, 1111000, 11100000, 110000000, 1000000000 };
    int NumSize[arraySize] = { 6,7,8,9,10 };
    
    int arr2D[20][20];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NumSize[i]; j++) {
            arr2D[i][j] = intToIntArray(a[i], NumSize[i])[j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NumSize[i]; j++) {
            cout << arr2D[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

How do I do it efficiently?
I don't want to use any vectors because I want to code it to my GPU later on.
Is there an efficient way to insert the int arrays directly into int matrix?

EDIT: (I kind of did what I wanted to do, I just made it static...)

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout; using std::endl;

int* intToIntArray(int input, int length) {
    static int output[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        output[i] = input % 10;
        input /= 10;
    }
    return output;
}

int main() {
    const int arraySize = 5;
    int a[arraySize] = { 111110, 1111000, 11100000, 110000000, 1000000000 };
    int NumSize[arraySize] = { 6,7,8,9,10 };
    int arr2D[20][20];

    for (int counter = 0; counter < arraySize; counter++) {
        int *arr1D = intToIntArray(a[counter], NumSize[counter]);

        for (int i = 0; i < NumSize[counter]; i++) {
            arr2D[counter][i] = arr1D[NumSize[counter]-1-i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < NumSize[i]; j++) {
            cout << arr2D[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `arr2D[counter] = arr1D;` exhibits undefined behavior when `count > 0`, by way of accessing an index out of bounds. `int** arr2D = new int*;` allocates just a single pointer, accessible as `arr2D[0]`. There's no element at `arr2D[1]`

Comment: `intToIntArray` returns an address of a local variable. The variable is destroyed when the function returns. The return value becomes a dangling pointer, any attempt to use it exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: In the second example, have `intToIntArray` take an `int*` pointer, and write to that buffer instead of `output`. `main` would pass `arr2D[i]` there. This way, `intToIntArray` would write directly into your matrix.

Comment: so instead of int* intToIntArray(int input, int length) ,
it should be void intToIntArray(int* buffer, int input, int length) ?

Comment: Yes, something along these lines.

Comment: ah I tried that, but it still didn't work... I kinda gave up on that approach.
I just did what I wanted to do, but not passing as a reference, I still returned an entire array but I made it static...
I will show you what I did, editing question...

Comment: If it didn't work, you did something wrong. `void intToIntArray(int* buffer, int input, int length)` absolutely can be made to work.

Comment: I have no idea, maybe I am just too stupid, could you please answer below with your example? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::cin;
void intToIntArray(int input, int length, int* &output) {
    output = new int[length];
    for(int i = length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        output[i] = input % 10;
        input /= 10;
    }
}
int main() {
    const int arraySize = 5;
    int a[] = { 111110, 1111000, 11100000, 110000000, 1000000000 };
    int NumSize[] = { 6,7,8,9,10 };
    int** arr2D = new int*[arraySize];
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
        intToIntArray(a[i], NumSize[i], arr2D[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: i will have to convert string or vector or any other types back into int if i do so, i dont want to.

Comment: I saw the comments above, and I think you can do it like this, edited comment

Comment: Oh great! It works wonderfully, thanks!

Comment: still i am a noob, idk we can actually reference and then dereference it at the same time...

Comment: If you want to change the value of a parameter after the function completes, you need to pass it as a reference or use a pointer, so you can also do like this: `void intToIntArray(int input, int length, int** output)` and call `intToIntArray(a[i],NumSize[i],&(arr2d[i]))`